# Get property of extension method's first argument with a lambda? (x => x.please)

Tags: c#, lambda, extension-methods

I'm trying to do this:

```
var order = new BuildingOrder(); //has a Sale property
var sale = order.ConfusinglyGet(() => order.Sale); //get value of order.Sale
```

So far all I can figure out is this:

```
public static O ConfusinglyGet<O>(this object i, Expression<Func<O>> expression)
{
    return expression.Compile()();
}
```

Will this return the property value?

I ultimately want to be able to check if `i` is null and optionally return `new O()` like

```
public static O FreemasonsOnly<I,O>(this I i, Expression<Func<O>> expression)
    where I : class,
    where O : class, new()
{
    return i != null ? expression.Compile()() : new O();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need an extra level of indirection with `Expression`, because you are not passing an expression in your example: you are passing a simple `Func<I,O>`

This should work for you:

```
public static O FreemasonsOnly<I,O>(this I i, Func<I,O> f)
where I : class where O : class, new()
{
    return i != null ? f(i) : new O();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What it looks like you want is:

```
public static O ConfusinglyGet<T, O>(this T i, Expression<Func<T, O>> expression) where O : class, new()
{
    return expression.Compile()(i) ?? new O();
}
```

Comment: that was my guess, but why does passing `i` to the compiled expression get the value of i's property? Is the compiled expression basically a `get` method that has a parent object parameter?

Comment: Compiling the expression yields a delegate that (in my example) takes an instance of type T and returns an instance of type O.  The subsequent parenthesis (i) passes the instance of T from the surrounding method (ConfusinglyGet) and returns the resulting instance of type O to the caller of ConfusinglyGet.

Comment: yes, I understand that part, but I guess I was wondering why it works that way. In other words what is the nature of the delegate? It reminds me a little of `PropertyInfo.GetValue(i, null)`. Does it represent or mimic the get accessor of the property or something?

Comment: The delegate is a function.  If you are a C++ programmer, it is roughly equivalent to a function pointer.  Calling it is equivalent to calling a function which retrieves and then returns the property in question.